# Saving plotted function as 3d matrix

Tags: matlab

In matlab I would like to get below defined function's 3D matrix representation. Function is      f(x,y) =  cos(x + y)^2. Range for x is from 0 to PI, and for y it is also 0 to PI. I wonder if this is possible?

For plotting this function in matlab I usedMuPad matlab's app.

```
plotfunc3d(cos(x + y)^2, x = 0..PI, y = 0..PI)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi with the following script I got the 3D plot of your function.

```
step = 0.05   ;
x = 1;
y = 1;
image = zeros(length(1:step:pi),length(1:step:pi));
for i =1:step:pi
    for j=1:step:pi
        image(x,y) = cos(i + j)^2;
        x = x+1;
    end
    x = 1;
    y = y + 1;
end

surf(image)
```